# Vue.js and loading pages dynamically with AJAX?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-resource

In my database web-application I need quite a lot of different pages, one for each table. Which pages are in the application is different for each user, so I don't want to include them all beforehand, because this would make things unneccessary big and maybe slow at startup.

In my application so far I have only 1 `Vue` instance, that holds the data for all pages, each in its own sub-object of `data`. Data is loaded on the fly as JSON with `vue-resource` (using `$http.get()` ), so at startup `data` is quite empty.

Now I need a way to load the HTML of the pages dynamically and bind them to the already existing `Vue` instance. I used to load pages with jQuery, but when I do this in this Vue application, the data is not binded to the content of the loaded page.

I looked into Vue components, but this seems more suited for repeatable (small) elements on a page, and not for entire pages, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

I also came across `vueify`, `browserify` and `Webpack`, but these seem a little too advanced for me right now. I just want to load in some HTML and use it with Vue, like it was already included before.

Could someone please explain the right way to do this?

***UPDATE***

Vue [partials](https://012.vuejs.org/api/elements.html#partial)***<sup>1</sup>*** seem to be a solution :

In your HTML-file :

`<partial :name="currentModule"></partial>`

and in your Javascript :

```
  var moduleid = "page1";
  var url = moduleid + ".html";

  myvue.$http.get(url, function(data, status, request){
      Vue.partial(moduleid, data);
      myvue.currentModule = moduleid;
  });
```

This uses`vue-resource` for the AJAX, but this could be done with `jquery.ajax()` or something else as well.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - `Vue.partial()` and `<partial />` support have been [removed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration?redirect=true#Vue-partial-removed) in Vue 2 and above.

Comment: Hello Dylan, did you found an answer to your question?

Comment: Hi Gurghet, I think partials can be the solution for this problem. See the update.

Comment: Hey @Dylan have you switched to Vue version 2. I don't see partials in version 2.